# Warning: mcrypt_decrypt(): Key of size 21 not supported..Only keys of sizes 16, 24 or 32 supported

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

Recently I upraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and PHP7. I have encrypt and decrypt methods. It was working on previous version.

Now I have problem while decrypting the string. 
The error says

```
Warning: mcrypt_decrypt(): Key of size 21 not supported by this algorithm
```

I have done necessary steps like installing ***mcrypt*** extensions and adding extension in ***php.ini***

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254432/mcrypt-decrypt-error-change-key-size

Comment: Please don't jump to conclusion without thorough verification. I did complete test and posted this question. Don't you see PHP7. It is working fine on older version. When I changed to PHP7 mcrypt_decrypt has stopped working.

Comment: Were you on PHP 5.5 before? This key size change landed in PHP 5.6. Also, [don't use mcrypt](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong), which will be deprecated in PHP 7.1 and removed in 7.2/8.0.

Comment: @user3226210 It does not matter, this error comes from the fact that from version 5.6 and onward *Invalid key and iv sizes are no longer accepted.*