# mcrypt_encrypt(): Key of size 8 not supported by this algorithm. Only keys of sizes 16, 24 or 32 supported in on line 57

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to add password encryption some time ago. The problem is that when I try to log in, it tells me that the password is not correct

```
    public static function fnEncrypt($sValue, $sSecretKey)
{
    return rtrim(
        base64_encode(
            mcrypt_encrypt(
                MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                $sSecretKey, $sValue, 
                MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, 
                mcrypt_create_iv(
                    mcrypt_get_iv_size(
                        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 
                        MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
                    ), 
                    MCRYPT_RAND)
                )
            ), "\0"
        );
}
```

DB:[enter link description here](https://pastebin.com/fPh8d1Tk)

Comment: Why don't you try SHA algorithms?

Comment: You might like it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1289114/8179245

Comment: What PHP version are you using? Check here too https://stackoverflow.com/a/27254578/8179245

Comment: SHA looks good but one of the most problems is i.m beginner, so idk if i know to switch encrypt method.For implementation i need to switch old public with new?

Comment: What algorithm has been used to insert the password?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php

Comment: I'm assuming, this function `public static function fnEncrypt` is being used for both operations (Insertion & selection). Are you using the stored procedures?

Comment: No, sorry.I have 2 publics, 1 for encrypt and 1 for decrypt:                    https://pastebin.com/2Ajyrb59 When i insert the password i use:https://pastebin.com/CaadXXzB

Comment: What I suggest, Passwords should always be one way encrypted so that no one can decrypt it. So rather than decrypting what available in the database, you should encrypt the typed password from the login page and match the encrypted with encrypted password... Say you have `asdfasdf232323` password in database which is in encrypt form of `Hello` and from logic page, I have provided the `Hello` as password, then you should encrypt the `Hello` again, and then compare it with the available one in the database